# Is it possible to add an HDR to the default 9 that blender comes with

Tags: hdri

I want to add it into the default library (drop down window headed Viewport Shading),NOT just create one using an environment texture node within the Shading setup.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Custom Lights Menu]
You can find the respective menu in the settings under *Lights*.
Any HDRI can be used here, but i'd recommend scaling it down for its use as a preview first

Comment: Thank you, just the job, perfect ;-)